# Uploading a base64 image as an image file

Tags: php

So I'm receiving an image in base64 encoding. I want to decode the image and upload it in a specific directory. The encoded file is an image and I'm using `$file = base64_decode($base64_string);` to decode it. Uploading it via `file_put_contents('/uploads/images/', $file);` always results in `failed to open stream: No such file or directory` error.

So, how do I take the decoded string, and upload it on a specific path?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong.

`/uploads/images`

is checking for a folder in the / directory called uploads. You should specify the full path to the folder:

`/var/www/vhosts/MYSITE/uploads/images`

Comment: I did try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` there but it still showed the same error. I'm on Linux and my DOCUMENT_ROOT is `/var/www/`

Comment: I doubt your web server has permission to write to /var/www, create a folder specifically for these images and chown it to www-data user. You need to be careful though because you're not validating what gets uploaded - anything could be put on your server.

Comment: I am on a Dev machine right now and I have given /var/www/myproject and its subdirectories 777 permission just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally solved using this:

```
<?php
$file = base64_decode($base); 
$photo = imagecreatefromstring($file);

//create a random name 
$RandomStr = md5(microtime());
$name = substr($RandomStr, 0, 3);
$name .= date('Y-m-d');
$name .= '.jpg';

//assign name and upload your image
imagejpeg($photo, 'images/'.$name, 100);
```